# Fix Gap on jQuery Autocomplete Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-autocomplete

## Gap

I'm working with jQuery Autocomplete. When I start type `a` and hover one of the option, I see a gap on the **right**.

[image]

---

## Inspect

Then, I try to inspect that list. I can see the style, but the dropdown-menu is gone.

[image]

---

## Dropdown Disappear

[image]

---

## CSS

```
{
    background-image: url("/images/photos/devices/xperia-z-ultra.jpg");
    background-size: 28px 19px;
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px .4em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    min-height: 0;
    /* support: IE7; */
    font-weight: normal;
}
.ui-widget-content a {
    color: #222222;
}
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-br {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

---

How do I fix that gap ?

I've tried messing around with the **toggle state** on `Chrome Dev Tool`, and still couldn't the style for that.

Any hints / suggestions ?

Comment: Hi,

This is a difficult one to help with without inspecting the element personally.

Nothing jumps out @ on the styling(CSS).  If I had to take a guess, I would put my money on padding of the child element in .ui-menu.  Try explicit padding styles on _ui-menu-item_ and _ui-menu-icons_, also check margins.

Comment: Which jquery library is it? Do you have a link to it? The panel will probably be opened and closed with javascript. So the library will probably expose some methods to open the select with javascript. You could then try to open it via the console of the inspector.

Comment: @blablabla : I used this plain https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: What I most of the times do when I having troubles like this, first I undock it to separate window. Then I move that window to my dropdown, so he is overlapping it. But you need to keep some space left to be able to still use the dropdown. Then you move your cursor to your inspector and voila your dropdown is still open.

Comment: @NiZa : That's a really cool trick. Thanks. I should have think of that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's jQuery UI's Autocomplete widget with a theme and some modifications; but if you select

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
```

In chrome dev tools on the left, on the right hand side you can change

```
display:none;
```

to

```
display:block;
```

to see whats going on and troubleshoot the offending element without it dissappearing